# Reload jsp page after computations

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

So my project demonstrates the results of a `k-means` clustering algorithm using servlets. 
When I cluster for the first time, everything works well and my program relocates the user to the `results.jsp` page.

But because `k-means` is a bit random at selecting centroids, I added a `re-cluster` feature in my code in the `results.jsp` which re-clusters my data with the settings originally used.

My servlet code for re-clustering looks like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    do stuff...
    //reload results page
    String htmlResponse = "<html><header><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; URL='results.jsp\" /></header></html>";
    writer.println(htmlResponse);
    //but this doesnt work...
}
```

So after the clustering is done, I want to reload the `resutls.jsp` page. I tried adding a `JavaScript` to my `jsp` page since `refresh` is a client side operation. But the problem with that approach is that `refresh` happens before the clustering is fully completed. So I get `Exceptions` when trying to print the results. Any advice?

My `refresh` script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function refresh() {
            location.reload(true);
        }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            function reCluster(cluster_id) {
                recluster();
            }
        </script>
```

and on the `.jsp` i'm calling this like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="generateArff" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onclick="reCluster(); refresh();">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Re-Cluster
     </button>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Generate file
     </button>
</form>

Can you advice on the matter?
```

Comment: Sorry, to me it is not clear where the exceptions are coming from - are they thrown by code inside the jsp you are trying to refresh? Do they get thrown the first time too or only after refresh?

Comment: You could do call the service from the client using AJAX or similar, and when the job is done, receive the callback.

Comment: @MarcoBolis for sanity checks, I setted up the clusters so initially they have an `index of -1` so if something was going on during my implementation I would pick up the error. For the re-cluster process, I 'm reseting all the existing clusters to their original settings. aka `index -1` so when I print them because they are stored in an `ArrayList`, well you can imagine what will happen with `index of -1`

Comment: @JoseQuintoZamora I'm already doing that. I'm calling the service from `AJAX`. Thing is that after the service is called, the client goes to the `refresh` service very fast, before there is enough time to calculate the `new` clusters

Comment: @Jack if you are calling the service through AJAX, then why are you refreshing? Sorry, I'm trying to better understand the issue

Comment: @MarcoBolis the service is called and executed properly. The problem is that the results have to be demonstrated when the computation is over. That's why I need to refresh the results page. If I manually refresh my `results.jsp` with the reload button then I get what I'm after. But I can't rely on the user to do that. it has to be automatic

Comment: @Jack when the AJAX call returns, the computation is yet to be completed? Is it fully async and the AJAX call just starts it? Am I understanding right?

Comment: @MarcoBolis exactly. I've added some extra code. That's why I thought that I should add the refreshing code on the `server-side` in order to take place right after the `computation`

Comment: @Jack, I would go around the problem making the `refresh` function be called in the `onreadystatechange` callback of your `XMLHttpRequest`... This would probably mean you have to defer the AJAX request completion until after you have completed the re-clustering. Then you send an OK message back to the browser and refresh the page.

Comment: @Marcobolis can you provide some code to try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, @MarcoBolis provided a very good and informative answer, and definitely gets a +1 from me.

However, I think that the most simple solutions are the most effective ones.

As I see your code, I can only assume that you are using an `AJAX` request to your `servlet` because I see 1 `html form` with 2 buttons that do different things. So, what I would do, is go to your `ReClusterServlet` and add the following:

```
public class ReClusterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        //Call your Cluster class and methods...
        //wait for it...

        //return something to your AJAX call.
        writer.print("refresh page");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

now, go to your `AJAX` request. 
I assume it will be in the `recluster()` function I see you are calling in the `head` of your `http` code.
so it must be something like this:

```
function recluster() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'ReClusterServlet',
        type:'POST'
    });
}
```

This thing, is calling the `servlet` but did you know that when your servlet was done with the computation it returned a `success` message to it??? But you are **ignoring** it!!!

it's this line `writer.print("refresh page");`

Now re-write the function as follows:

```
function recluster() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'ReClusterServlet',
        type:'POST',
        success:function() {   //handle the successful return by reloading the current page
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Again, these are speculations because they seem a bit incomplete, so feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but I have a strong feeling that you need to study a bit more on the `client-server architecture`, `JQuery` and `AJAX`

Answer (score 2):

I understand you are issuing an AJAX call to the server to start an asynchronous task, performing the clustering.

You could notify the client of task completion by means of a message returned through the XHR:

```js
function reCluster() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'ReClusterServlet', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            // Refresh if everything went OK
            if (xhr.responseText === 'Done') refresh();
        }
    };
}
```

The tricky part is handling the notification Java-side.

If you are using Servlet API 3.x+, then you are lucky: just make your request an async one:

```java
public class ReClusterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Defer the request to this HTTP request to later
        AsyncContext asyncCtx = request.startAsync(request, response);
        asyncCtx.setTimeout(0);

        // Start the long running computation in another thread,
        // passing the AsyncContext
        new MyLongRunningTask(asyncCtx).start();
    }
}
```

Then complete it in the other thread:

```
public class MyLongRunningTask {
    private final AsyncContext asyncCtx;
    public MyLongRunningTask(AsyncContext asyncCtx) {
        this.asyncCtx = asyncCtx;
    }

    // ...

    private void finish() {
        // Send the response asynchronously
        Writer out = this.asyncCtx.getResponse().getWriter();
        out.println("Done");
        out.flush();

        this.asyncContext.complete();
    }
}
```

If instead you are using an older version of the Servlet API, you will have to make the serving thread (the one on which the `doGet` method gets called) block until the computation is finished.

If you have a reference to the thread on which the computation is performed available, you can call its `join` method to await termination:

```
public class ReClusterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Thread async = new MyLongRunningThread();
        async.start();

        // Await end of computation
        try {
            async.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Computation was interrupted...
        }

        response.getWriter().println("Done");
    }
}
```

If instead the computation task is queued for execution, for example by an `ExecutorService`, you have to use `wait/notify`:

```
public class ReClusterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private ExecutorService executor;
    // ...

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        MyLongRunningRunnable task = new MyLongRunningRunnable();

        synchronized (task) {
            executor.execute(task);

            // Put current thread to sleep until task is no more RUNNING
            // (assuming state is a property of MyLongRunningRunnable)
            while (task.getState() == State.RUNNING) {
                try {
                    task.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Computation was interrupted...
                }
            }
        }

        response.getWriter().println("Done");
    }
}
```

Assuming that the async task calls `notify` when done:

```
public class MyLongRunningRunnable implements Runnable {
    private State state = State.RUNNING;

    // ...

    private synchronized void finish() {
        this.state = State.DONE;
        this.notify();
    }
}
```

**NOTE** that these two solutions that block the request thread **may** cause performance issues if you have **lots** of incoming requests and the clustering job takes very long.